# Offline Reverse CLGeocoder at Country Level

Tags: iphone, ios, geolocation, reverse-geocoding

The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/Reference/Reference.html) of CLGeocoder states:

> An iOS-based device must have access to the network in order for the
>   geocoder object to return detailed placemark information. Although,
>   the geocoder **stores enough information locally to report the localized
>   country name and ISO country code for many locations**. If country
>   information is not available for a specific location, the geocoder may
>   still report an error to your completion block.

Do anyone have any experience whit this? Sitting in Oslo, Norway I get an error when trying to look up the country offline. So what is **many locations**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your cache. If you have some information on your local disk cahsed that can help get the location, you wont need an online connection.